# Visual studio development server very slow on IE, normal on chrome or firefox

Tags: performance, visual-studio-2010

When i start the development server (Ctrl+F5 - not debugging) it takes a very long while to load on IE, but loads normally on chrome/firefox. When the page finally load, the images take a long time to load as well, and they are loaded one by one, with about 30 seconds between each.

Anyone know what could be ?

Using IE9 / Visual Studio 2010 / Windows 7 64bits

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue for me too. Love the integrated debug environment, but if you have a lot of JS to debug, VS takes ages to connect the debugger to IE.
My best suggestion, is to turn everying you dont need off.

1. Use "connect to existing web site" and connect to the web server address (I use IIS)
2. Turn off ASP.NET debugging if you are not debugging .net in the same session
3. Turn off Build (Before running start page) under build in your properties page
4. When you run are running for the first time, close the solution explorer window so it does not start when in debugging mode. This will prevent window from having to update heaps of EVAL and dynamic JS nodes.
5. Make sure you have maxage set to 0 in your web.config

   ```
   <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="00:00:00" />
   ```

this will prevent IE from aggressively caching all of your javascript

I have managed to halve my loading from 30 seconds to 15.

Hope this helps.